# is there a command to clear the worksheet from all output? (not using GUI)

Tags: maple

I use worksheet (not document mode).
I know one can do  `Edit>Remove Output>From Worksheet` to "Removes Maple output from all execution groups in a worksheet."

But I could not find a command to do this. I need to do this, since when I run a loop as in

```
for i from 1 to n do
    some_function();
od
```

And the function above say prints to the screen (i.e. worksheet currently open) lots of information, then the worksheet slows down and I really also do not want to see the logging from all the calls accumulated any way. I just need to see prints from one iteration only at a time.

(Maple has other problems with having large output accumulate in worksheet also, but this is for another topic).

I'd like to do something like this

```
for i from 1 to n do
    some_function();
    delete_all_output_in_current_worksheet();
od;
```

So only one call's output shows up as the `some_function` is running.

In Matlab, this is easily done using [clc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clc.html) which clears the command windows in Matlab.

Is there something like the above in Maple?

Maple 2018.1 on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no programmatic way to clear all the output of the current worksheet.

But you can push the running result from `some_function()` (each time through the loop) to Embedded Components, eg. TextBox, MathContainer, etc.

You don't even have to manually insert such Components from the palettes. Instead you can use the `DocumentTools:-Tabulate` command to programmatically insert a tabulated collection of components right after the current Execution Group.

For example, as 1D code in a Worksheet, you could have these blocks of code in three separate Execution Groups.

```
restart;
```

and,

```
some_function:=proc(i)
    int( sin(x)^i, x);
end proc:

Leafcutoff := 150:
```

and,

```
# Put all this in the same Execution Group
for i from 1 to 111 by 10 do

  res[i] := some_function(i);

  K := MmaTranslator:-Mma:-LeafCount(res[i]);
  if K <= Leafcutoff then
    L := res[i];
  else
    L := sprintf("LeafCount > %a",Leafcutoff);
  end if;
  DocumentTools:-Tabulate(
      [["i","LeafCount","result"],
       [sprintf("%a",i), K, L]],
      ':-weights'=[10,10,40],
      ':-fillcolor'=((T,i,jj)->`if`(i=1,"grey",
                                    "white")),
      ':-widthmode'=':-pixels',
      ':-width'=600);
  Threads:-Sleep(1.5); # delay at least 1.5 sec

end do:
DocumentTools:-Tabulate([[]]):
```

I put in a time-delay of 1.5 seconds just to illustrate it working. You can adjust that, or remove it.

The last call to `Tabulate` is only there to blank it out, when the loop is finished.

The GUI Table inserted by `Tabulate` actually appears in a region right after the Execution Group. Only one such region appears, per Execution Group. Basically, each call to Tabulate overwrites that region.

If you changed the `end do:` to `end do;` then all the regular output would also be shown, as usual for a loop.